# Does sharepoint designer 2013 requires SP server or SP foundation ..?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, office365

I am running a site on office 365 online and can't install SP server or foundation on my personal computer due to its extensive hardware requirements. But I just need to use SP designer to modify master pages and styles sheet.

So, is that possible to install SP designer without having SP server installed..?

PS:
This is a public facing site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't require SP server installed (You can install it and use on computer without SPS installed on it). You need just download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491), install and connect to SharePoint instance you want to modify.

Comment: Thank u @Greg. This is exactly what I was assuming but I was just wanted to make it sure.. Can I edit master pages, style sheets for my public facing site in SP designer..?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can find similar question here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/475b2690-cace-4f4a-8c97-b1817a9bffc0/branding-sharepoint-public-facing-website-2013-online?forum=sharepointcustomization